# Are there any other options similar to /img/loading.gif, where to put your own gif?

Tags: visualforce

I implemented a spinner like below, everything is working but I want to use a different gif, are there any other options in /img/ ? Where is this folder ? And, what other images are in there ?

```
<apex:actionStatus id="modifyingPractice">
                   <apex:facet name="start">
                  <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: 0.75; z-index: 1000; background-color: black;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1001; margin: 30% 50%">
                        <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 2px;">
                                      <img src="/img/loading.gif" style="float: left; margin: 8px;" width="35" height="35" />
                        </div>
                   </div>
                  </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>
```

I see [here](http://sfdcrocket.blogspot.com/2017/10/add-spinner-on-visualforce-page.html) that theree is a "loading32.gif", which is cool looking, but what else is there ?

Comment: have you tried using a static resource?

Comment: I'll try that, I just didn't want to go to the trouble if there was a bunch of spinners already in /img but it looks like there's only two.

Comment: http://www.force2b.net/index.php/2010/08/salesforce-icons/ and  https://force2b-icons-developer-edition.na39.force.com/icons/